# Проблема с хешированием пароля (Соль)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При создании пользователя, заданный пароль должен пройти хеширование солью, и отправиться в БД. Но он застревает, отладчик показывает:

> string(60) "$2y$10$6W4gLLV/iDYus9U1X6jPrOhTj7ZgSJqVjKnAaC4N7tgYnGN1bLeSG" Ошибка

Вот кусок кода. В первый раз пользуюсь данной функцией. Объясните, что я делаю не так.

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pass'];

    $hashed_password = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    var_dump($hashed_password);

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, lastname, email, password) VALUES (:name, :lastname, :email, :pass)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $pwd);
    $falg = $stmt->execute();

    if ($falg) {
            echo 'Успешно';
            die;
    } else {
            echo 'Ошибка';
            die;
    }
```

Comment: Здесь нет проблемы с хешированием. Здесь просто ошибка выполнения запроса. Надо выяснить текст ошибки и починить.

Comment: Также неясно почему в запрос подставляется нехешированный пароль

Comment: @u_mulder string(60) "$2y$10$rOIe34C3zxQRjZggXbKtzehRoZ.GmAEJZT71L8Ph8MsvIEiSdUs4G" Ошибка PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Вот вся ошибка. На сколько я понял. Он говорит о том, что обрабатывает 0 строк. Но в базу данных добавил открытый пароль.

Comment: Ошибку я убрал. Но теперь только в открытом виде отправляет в БД.

Comment: Наверно потому что не та переменная используется в bindParam, не?

Comment: @u_mulder я заменил. Всё тоже самое. $stmt->bindParam(':pass', $pwd);

Comment: Думаешь я телепат и знаю что такое `$pwd`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107758/discussion-between--and-u-mulder).